# Why does pxssh .before method return delimiters?

Tags: ssh, python-3.3, pexpect

Looking for a way to return just the stdout string when using the sendline method from pxssh module.  Here is an example of code.

```
import pxssh
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.force_password = True
s.login('host', 'user', 'password')
s.prompt()
print(s.before)
```

I get a string with delimters returned.  Is this avoidable?  I'd like to skip the step of cleaning this up to a usable string with regex if possible.

```
>>> print(s.before)
b'uptime\r\n 11:53:28 up 14 days, 19:13,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.19, 0.17\r\n'
```

Comment: What do you want instead? A string with the CRLF removed?  A list, one string per line? The fact that there are options explains why the output is left as received from the remote host.

Comment: Correct chepner.  I would like the output to read 'uptime 11:53:28 up 14 days, 19:13,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.19, 0.17' if that functionality is possible with just this method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to modify the string after you retrieve it.

```
print(s.before.replace("\r\n", ""))
```

Comment: This put me on the right track chepner! >>> s.before.replace("\r\n","") Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object >>> The pxssh.before method returns a byte object. >>> out = s.before >>> print(out) b'uptime\r\n 11:53:28 up 14 days, 19:13, 1 user, load average: 0.22, 0.19, 0.17\r\n' >>> type(out) <class 'bytes'> Decoding the object got me where i wanted to be. >>> print(out.decode('utf-8')) uptime 11:53:28 up 14 days, 19:13, 1 user, load average: 0.22, 0.1